# Jetpack compose text background size is bigger

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I am trying to figure out why text background on bottom and top is bigger than needed, as you see on this picture, color on start and end is just big as the end of the text, but on bottom and top, it is a little more bigger and get more space than the text itself. How can I fix this and why is it like that?

```
@Composable
fun Text() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Cyan),
            text = "Some random text",
            fontFamily = RobotoMedium,
            fontSize = Resizable.customFont(26),
            color = ScheduledArrivedColor
        )
    }
}
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: You must be experiencing the infamous Dhuvikov's illusion. To be sure, try DECREASING the size of the text and see if it appears to be in the centre.

Comment: The bottom padding is fine, if you add a 'g' or a 'p' you will see why. The top padding could be slightly smaller, in which case you can try with different line heights. 
Also, you can use this ascii character to properly test: █

Comment: Hey, Svilen. Did you find the reason?